# What vinegar was used in 1904?

Tags: vinegar, history

What kind of vinegar would best replicate that was being used in the USA, upper Midwest in a recipe dated 1904? It is a potato salad recipe. The potatos & egg yolks are mashed together with minced cabbage & celery. Dressing has vinegar, egg yolks, salt, pepper & mustard (we assumed dry). We used white vinegar to mixed reviews. Somewhat strong vinegar flavor.

Comment: Can you share the recipe? That'll help.

Comment: You need to tell use something more about the recipe than its geographic origin and age. What are you cooking: meat? vegetables? a dessert?

Comment: Dianne / DBRoman - if you want to merge your accounts, see [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 6):

[Heinz started making products in the 1870's](http://www.heinzvinegar.com/history.aspx) and was bottling and selling vinegar in the 1880's, so probably ordinary white vinegar or possibly malt vinegar (depending on recipe) would work well.

Comment: Good answer, but could have been apple cider vinegar or a pickling vinegar, depending on the specific recipe. Heinz made many varieties back then.

Comment: I agree; I was going for the more common ones. I suspect it would be regional depending on where in the midwest, as apples and a variety of different crops are grown in that area, particularly corn and wheat (both used to make white vinegar) in the early days. I guess apples would have been pretty common in the upper midwest, so that is a possibility too. Pickling vinegar is just white vinegar with spices added, so I would be a little surprised to see it in a recipe that wasn't pickling something, though we don't know this from OP.

Comment: If it was, say, a salad dressing, cider vinegar would have been more likely.  That's why I was waiting for clarification from the OP.